# JDBI manual transaction management

Tags: java, jdbc, transactions, jdbi

I'm using JDBI for preparing data for test scenarios (setting up preconditions) in a separate project (rest-assured stuff). Now I have to use those JDBI-powered Daos for integration tests in a production project.

An example data setup Dao looks like this:

```
class DocumentDao(jdbi: Jdbi) : DefaultCrudRepository<Document>(jdbi) {

    /* ... */

    override fun save(entity: Document, handle: Handle): Int {
        return handle.createUpdate(
                """
                INSERT INTO documents (
                    /* ... */
                )
                VALUES (
                    /* ... */
                )
                """
        )
                .bindBean(entity)
                .execute()
    }
    /* ... */
}
```

And now I must use it together with a production persistence framework, because each scenario in integration tests is performed in a single transaction. So both precondition insertion and production data modification in DB must happen in a single transaction and be rolled back. Like this:

```
@Test
public void LoadDocument_001() throws Exception
{
    // Start a transaction
    startTx();

    Integer id = testDocumentDao.nextIdFromSequence();

    // Insert fake document into DB as a test precondition
    test.document.Document document = new test.document.Document(/* ... */);

    testDocumentDao.save(document);

    // Production Dao (subject) is called
    Document loadedDocument = subject.load(id.toString());

    // Rollback the transaction
    rollbackTx();
}
```

startTx() and rollbackTx() are methods I can use to manually control a transaction by communicating with a connection directly. BUT! I can't control transactions for those JDBI-powered Daos. Every operation that is using JDBI happens to be automatically committed by JDBI. So Document I've created as a precondition is left in a DB after test finishes.

Note: of course, I'm using the same connection instance in JDBI and in production persistence layer.

So I have two questions:

1. How do I do manual transaction management for JDBI-only operations? For instance, I have two Daos (DocumentDao and CustomerDao) built like the example above. I want to call methods on both of them, but I want all changes to happen in a single transaction. And then I want to roll back that transaction.
2. How do I do manual transaction management for JDBI operation mixed with  other non-JDBI code? E.g. I'm using DocumentDao and also some production code which is changing DB state too. How can I control a transaction using JDBI and/or communicating with a connection directly? Do I have to somehow disable automatic transaction management in JDBI? I tried doing it using fake TransactionHandler with empty methods, but it doesn't take any effect.

Comment: 1. Use the same Handle instance with both daos, and use the transaction methods begin(), commit(), rollback() etc on Handle.

Comment: 2. To be on the same transaction, all operations must happen over the same connection. Use handle.getConnection() for your non-Jdbi code. Use the transaction methods from Handle, and don't call Connection.setAutoCommit()